# R plot efficiently thousands of spheres deformed in ellipsoids in 3D with transparency

Tags: r, 3d, visualization, tensor, rgl

I need to really speeding up a small piece of code that deforms about 3000 spheres in the 3d rgl space according to a 3x3 tensors list that transforms them in ellipsoids. Moreover, I would need transparent color ("alpha" argument <1). Then I want to plot them rapidly and efficiently. I would like to have the same performance of spheres3d() but of course it is not the case...(run the code below). Here below my code with necessary functions for a fully reproducible example. Could you help me in doing this? Many thanks in advance.
Paolo

```
library(Morpho)
library(Rvcg)
library(rgl)

rep.row<-function(x,n){  #### rep rows of a matrix
  matrix(rep(x,each=n),nrow=n)
}

traslamesh<-function(mesh,c){ #### just translate a mesh in the 3d space according a position vector
  newvb<-t(mesh$vb[-4,])+rep.row(c,nrow(t(mesh$vb[-4,])))
  newmesh<-list(vb=t(cbind(newvb,1)),it=mesh$it)
  class(newmesh)<-"mesh3d"
  newmesh
}

defosph<-function(sphere,mat,after=T){#### this deforms a sphere in an ellipspoid according to a 3x3 tensor 
  if(after==T){newvb<-t(sphere$vb[-4,])%*%t(mat)}else{newvb<-t(mat%*%sphere$vb[-4,])}
  newmesh<-list(vb=t(cbind(newvb,1)),it=sphere$it)
  class(newmesh)<-"mesh3d"
  newmesh
}
creasph<-function(radius=1,centroid=c(0,0,0),subdivision=1){  #### just a wrap of vcgSphere
  temp_sphere<-vcgSphere(subdivision = subdivision)
  temp_sphere$vb[1,]<-temp_sphere$vb[1,]+centroid[1]
  temp_sphere$vb[2,]<-temp_sphere$vb[2,]+centroid[2]
  temp_sphere$vb[3,]<-temp_sphere$vb[3,]+centroid[3]
  final_sphere<-scalemesh(temp_sphere, radius, center = "none")
  return(final_sphere)
}
positions<-matrix(rnorm(9000,2,20),ncol=3) ###### positions where we want to plot
spheres3d(positions,alpha=0.5) #### very fast to plot and reasonably fast to naviagate in the 3d rgl window

tensor1<-matrix(rnorm(9),ncol=3) #### a random tensor; let's use the same one for deforming all the 3000 spheres. In the real application each sphere will have its own tensor.

open3d()
for(i in 1:dim(positions)[1]){  #### embarrassingly slow ......
  sphi<-creasph(radius=1,subdivision=2)
  shade3d(traslamesh(scalemesh(defosph(sphi,tensor1,after=F),1,center="none"),positions[i,]),col=2,alpha=0.5)
print(i)
  }
```

###### I want to deform the spheres in ellipsoids according to n tensors and plot them efficiently

Comment: Probably the fastest way to do this is to generate one sphere and then use it as a 3D sprite.  But if each ellipsoid gets its own transformation matrix, it will still be slow, and transparency will make it slower.

Comment: One thing that will make a really large difference is to avoid updating the plot after every change.  Call `par3d(skipRedraw=TRUE)` at the beginning, and `par3d(skipRedraw=FALSE)` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you are doing that make this code slow.  First, you are plotting 3000 objects, and updating the display after every one.  That's easy to fix:  call `par3d(skipRedraw=TRUE)` at the beginning, and `par3d(skipRedraw=FALSE)` at the end, and the drawing will be much faster.

The second thing you are doing is much harder to fix.  You are constructing ellipsoids as meshes, which makes each one a collection of 320 triangles.  Since you have 3000 of these, you've got nearly a million triangles to plot.  `rgl` can handle that, but what makes it really slow is that you are declaring them all to be transparent.  To plot these, it needs to sort all million triangles in order from most distant to closest to plot them.  Every time it switches from plotting a triangle in one ellipsoid to a triangle in a different one, it needs to go through a fairly expensive context change.

If you set `alpha = 1` you'll get a much faster display because sorting isn't needed.

The other thing you could do is to merge all 3000 ellipsoids into one huge mesh.  It will still need to sort the triangles, but won't need all those context changes.

The code below illustrates the suggestions.  I'll assume you keep your original code to setup the functions.

```
# Skip redrawing and set alpha = 1

open3d()
par3d(skipRedraw=TRUE)
for(i in 1:dim(positions)[1]){  #### reasonably fast
  sphi<-creasph(radius=1,subdivision=2)
  shade3d(traslamesh(scalemesh(defosph(sphi,tensor1,after=F),1,center="none"),positions[i,]),col=2,alpha=1)
  print(i)
}
par3d(skipRedraw=FALSE)

# Keep alpha = 0.5, but plot just one big mesh

open3d()
for(i in 1:dim(positions)[1]){  #### pretty slow, but faster than the original
  sphi<-creasph(radius=1,subdivision=2)
  sphi <- traslamesh(scalemesh(defosph(sphi,tensor1,after=F),1,center="none"),positions[i,])
  if (i == 1) result <- sphi else result <- merge(result, sphi)
  print(i)
}
shade3d(result, col=2, alpha = 0.5)
```

The second method is still pretty slow:  it does a lot of allocations doing all those merges.  You could speed up the construction parts a lot by working with mesh internals.  It is also pretty slow in updates, because of the sorting needed for `alpha = 0.5`.

The reason the built-in spheres display is so fast is that it doesn't attempt to do such a good job.  It sorts the sphere centers, not all the triangles making up each sphere.  If you set `fastTransparency = FALSE`, it will slow down a lot, because then it will sort all the triangles.  It also uses the equivalent of "sprites", initializing just one sphere and redrawing it in lots of different locations.  Sprites would work for your example, but not if you needed different transformations on every ellipsoid.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! In any case you really speeded up the code! The fact is that I **really need* transparency as inside the ellipsoids I will plot the Principal strain Direction segments (=ellipsoid axes). Thus transparency is mandatory....In any case the second solution is very clever!