# Display multiple cylinders efficiently in RGL Plot

Tags: r, 3d, rgl

I am trying to plot cylinder models of trees in R, which consist of several thousand cylinders. Currently, I am trying to use the `rgl` package for this task. Until now, I looped through all cylinders and added them separately to the 3D Plot.

Here an example with dummy data:

```
# dummy data
cylinder <- data.frame(start_X = rep(0:2, each = 2),
                       start_Y = rep(0:1, 3),
                       start_Z = 0,
                       end_X = rep(0:2, each = 2),
                       end_Y = rep(0:1, 3),
                       end_Z = 1)
radii <- seq(0.1, 0.5, length.out = 6)

# plotting
open3d()
for (i in 1:nrow(cylinder)) {
  cyl <- cylinder3d(
    center = cbind(
      c(cylinder$start_X[i], cylinder$end_X[i]),
      c(cylinder$start_Y[i], cylinder$end_Y[i]),
      c(cylinder$start_Z[i], cylinder$end_Z[i])),
    radius = radii[i],
    closed = -2)
  shade3d(cyl, col = "steelblue")
}
axes3d(edges = c("x", "y", "z"))
```

[image: example output]

However, this approach takes ages when trying to plot several thousand cylinders. Is there a way to hand over several cylinder objects at once to the `shade3d()` function? Can I create several separate cylinders in one call of `cylinder3d()`? Or am I possibly using wrong functions or an inappropriate R package?

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/q/69259197/2554330 is similar, where many ellipsoids being drawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few possibilities.

The easiest change is to tell `rgl` not to update the display until you are finished updating it using the `par3d(skipRedraw=TRUE)` option.  You need to run `par3d(skipRedraw=FALSE)` when you want to see the updates.  That often makes enough of a speedup.

If all of  your cylinders were the same shape (but maybe rescaled), you could use `sprites3d`; but you are varying the radius separately from the height, so that's not possible.

To do what you asked for (put them all into one `shade3d` call) you could make a shape list.  For example, after editing to allow separate colors,

```
cylinder <- data.frame(start_X = rep(0:2, each = 2),
                       start_Y = rep(0:1, 3),
                       start_Z = 0,
                       end_X = rep(0:2, each = 2),
                       end_Y = rep(0:1, 3),
                       end_Z = 1)
radii <- seq(0.1, 0.5, length.out = 6)
colors <- rainbow(6)

library(rgl)
thelist <- lapply(1:6, function(i) {
  cyl <- cylinder3d(
    center = cbind(
      c(cylinder$start_X[i], cylinder$end_X[i]),
      c(cylinder$start_Y[i], cylinder$end_Y[i]),
      c(cylinder$start_Z[i], cylinder$end_Z[i])),
    radius = radii[i],
    closed = -2)
  cyl$material$color <- colors[i]
  cyl
})

# plotting
open3d()
shade3d(shapelist3d(thelist, plot = FALSE))
axes3d(edges = c("x", "y", "z"))
```

The `shapelist3d()` function can take a list of meshes as above, or take a single mesh and with other arguments reshape and duplicate it.  There probably won't be much difference in the speed.

Comment: Thank you very much! Originally it took about 15min or something,. With apply it takes 13s and when skipping the redraw it takes 33s. So quite the improvement I would say! :)

Comment: Sorry to bother, do you know if there is a chance to assign different colors to the single cylinders when using the shapelist? I have a different color for each cylinder. If not, I will just stick with skipping the redrawing.

Comment: Sure, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks again! I did not know I could actually assign a color to a cylinder, it's my first time working with `rgl`. This saves my day :)

Comment: The tricky thing would be to make each cylinder multi-colored.  It is possible, but you'd have to guess at the order for colors to be specified in the material, and it might change if cylinder3d is ever updated.